# How to get ALL combinations of a list of words using ANY number of words

Tags: php, math, permutation, combinations

I have searched but I can't find anything that matches my query. I have seen lots of solutions where people want all combinations of numbers/words that use ALL the options, but none like this...

Here's an example:

```
apple pear
```

This should generate:

> apple
>   pear
>   apple pear
>   pear apple

Or even...

```
apple pear banana
```

> apple
>   pear
>   banana
>   apple pear
>   apple banana
>   pear banana
>   ...
>   ...
>   banana pear apple

The key is, ALL possible combinations that use any of the words zero or one times in ANY order. :)

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combinations, Dispositions and Permutations in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679605/combinations-dispositions-and-permutations-in-php)

Comment: what you want is statistically called Permutation (as opposed to Combination, etc.)

Comment: @user957593 -- I updated my answer with some working code ^_^

Comment: Is `apple apple` valid in this context?

Comment: @ircmaxell - **zero or one times** in the OP... guess no `apple apple` then, unless apple is on the list twice

Comment: @ircmaxell same as if `apple apple apple ...` is valid....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**FINAL ANSWER AT THE BOTTOM**

---

Pseudocode (has not been tested)

```
$str = "apple pear banana";
$str_splode = explode(' ',$str);

echo showCombo($str_splode[0], $str_splode);

function showCombo($str, $arr){
    $ret = '';
    foreach($arr as $val){
       if($val != $str)
           $ret .= $str.showCombo($val, $arr);
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

---

Running code:  http://codepad.org/IUPJbhI7

```
<?php

$str = "apple pear banana orange";
$str_splode = explode(' ',$str);
print_r(showCombo(array(), $str_splode));

function showCombo($str_arr, $arr){
    $ret = array();
    foreach($arr as $val){
       if(!in_array($val, $str_arr)){
           $temp = $str_arr;
           $temp[] = $val;
           print_r($temp);
           $comb = showCombo($temp, $arr);
           if(count($comb) > 0)
              $ret[] = $comb;
       }
    }
    return $ret;
}
?>
```

This returns **all** possible combinations

---

Or this one looks better: http://codepad.org/KCLeRUYs

```
<?php

$str = "apple pear banana orange";
$str_splode = explode(' ',$str);
print_r(showCombo(array(), $str_splode));

function showCombo($str_arr, $arr){
    $ret = array();
    foreach($arr as $val){
       if(!in_array($val, $str_arr)){
           $temp = $str_arr;
           $temp[] = $val;
           $ret[$val] = $temp;
           $ret[$val][] = showCombo($temp, $arr);
       }
    }
    return $ret;
}

?>
```

---

Or if you want to look at flat keys: http://codepad.org/95aNQzXB

---

### Final Answer:

And this one lists them all: http://codepad.org/vndOI9Yj

```
<?php

$str = "apple pear banana orange";
$str_splode = explode(' ',$str);
$combos = showCombo(array(), $str_splode);
foreach($combos as $key=>$array){
    echo $key.PHP_EOL;
    displayArrayByKey($key, $array);
}


function displayArrayByKey($str, $arr){
    foreach($arr as $key=>$array){
          $string = $str. " " . $key;
          echo $string . PHP_EOL; 
          if(count($array)> 0){
              displayArrayByKey($string, $array);
          }
    }
}

function showCombo($str_arr, $arr){
    $ret = array();
    foreach($arr as $val){
       if(!in_array($val, $str_arr)){
           $temp = $str_arr;
           $temp[] = $val;
           $ret[$val] = showCombo($temp, $arr);
       }
    }
    return $ret;
}

?>
```

Comment: @Justin see the update to the code on the bottom of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can download this class: http://pear.php.net/package/Math_Combinatorics

and use it like:

```
$combinatorics = new Math_Combinatorics;

$words_arr = array(
    'one'   => 'a',
    'two'   => 'b',
    'three' => 'c',
    'four'  => 'd',
    );

for ($i=count($words_arr)-1;$i>=1;$i--) {
    echo '<br><br>' . $i . ':<br>';
    $combinations_arr = $combinatorics->combinations($words_arr, $i);
    foreach ($combinations_arr as $combinations_arr_item) {
        echo implode(', ', $combinations_arr_item) . '<br>';
    }
}
```