# how do i create all possible letter combinations with php

Tags: php

I looked around stack overflow and couldn't find a sample on what I needed.
how would I create something like this?

so lets say i want all possible combinations of up to 5 characters.
the output would look like this:

```
aaaaa
aaaab
aaaac
aaaad

..etc
```

Comment: @MattBall Nah why would he do that when he could be spoon fed an answer?

Comment: i dont even have a clue of how it would be written.

Comment: [Start with a `for` loop.](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combinations, Dispositions and Permutations in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679605/combinations-dispositions-and-permutations-in-php)

Comment: @Austin Salonen Funny that this question was closed but the question you've linked to is even shorter without even any examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, because I believe that you don't have any clue what to do, I will give you a short code example. It is not perfect and its written down in a couple of minutes but it should bring you on the right way:

```
$values = 'abcd';
run(strlen($values), 0 );

function run($length, $pos, $out = '' ) {
    global $values;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i) {
        if ($pos < $length ) {
            run($length, $pos + 1, $out . $values[$i]);
        }
    }
    echo $out.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Next time try first and post your question with the code you have written even if it is nearly nothing and looks stupid for you. But in the end it will show that you make own work and don't hope to get your work done for free without thinking by yourself.